# Writing multiple matrices to an ASCII file which can be read back into MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to write multiple matrices from my C++ program to a single ASCII text file, which can be read into MATLAB by some inbuilt MATLAB function as separate matrices. Does such a function exist?

(The standard `dlmread` function just reads one matrix per text file)

Comment: Have you try to use Import data matlab tool ? Matlab have  csvread function.

Comment: Depends on how the file is structured - how would the matrices be separated in the file, are they of some consistent size, etc. I can think of a few tricksy ways of approaching it (probably involving `textscan`), but it would be much easier to just write them out into separate files.

Comment: Why not write the multiple matrices to a binary file and then use **fopen** and **fread** to get the data.  For every matrix written to file you could prepend with the number of rows and columns (as uint8 or uint16 or whatever) then use **fread** to read that data into a matrix of the specified dimensions (assuming the data type for all elements in the matrix is double or whatever you used to write out to the binary file).